Projection maps fibred product of same object twice can be chosen to be equal?
Suppose $\mathscr{C}$ is a (locally small)category and $X,Y \in \mathscr{C}$ and $X \rightarrow Y$ is a single morphism, what I am curious about is if the projections $X \times_Y X \rightarrow X$ of the fibred product $X \times_Y X$ as defined by its universal propery can be chosen (as in up to isomorphism) to be equal. My question comes from three different questions on this site, this one seems to say that these projections can be chosen equal (the way that I read the top answer is that this is the case even if $\pi$ isn't a monomorphism). Also this question might hint that this is the case (see "...possibly $f = g = h$..."). But this question (altough it is only answered for products not fibred) seems to hint that this might not be the case.
I came up with the example
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{R}^3 @>{p_{12}}>> \mathbb{R}^2\\
@V{p_{13}}VV @V{p_{1}}VV\\
\mathbb{R}^2 @>{p_{1}}>> \mathbb{R}
\end{CD}
where $p_{12},$ $p_{13}$ and $p_1$ are the projections $x \mapsto (x_1,x_2),$ $x \mapsto (x_1,x_3)$ and $x \mapsto x_1$ for $x = (x_1,x_2,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ respectively. This is a fibred product $\mathbb{R}^2 \times_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{R}^2$ as for any set $W$ with
\begin{CD}
W @>{\mu}>> \mathbb{R}^2\\
@V{\nu}VV @V{p_{1}}VV\\
\mathbb{R}^2 @>{p_{1}}>> \mathbb{R}
\end{CD}
we can write $\mu = (\mu_1,\mu_2)$ and $\nu = (\nu_1,\nu_2)$ with $\mu_1 = \nu_1,$ which then induces the unique map $f: W \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ defined as $f = (\mu_1 = \nu_1,\mu_2,\nu_2).$ Hence it is a fibred product. In this case clearly $p_{12} \neq p_{13},$ but if instead I consider$\require{enclose}$
\begin{CD}
\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\mathbb{R}} @>{\enclose{horizontalstrike}{p^{1}}}>> \enclose{horizontalstrike}{\mathbb{R}^2}\\
@V{\enclose{horizontalstrike}{p^{1}}}VV @V{\enclose{horizontalstrike}{p_{1}}}VV\\
\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\mathbb{R}^2} @>{\enclose{horizontalstrike}{p_{1}}}>> \enclose{horizontalstrike}{\mathbb{R}}
\end{CD}
where $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{p^1}$ is the map $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{x \mapsto (x,0),}$ then similarly $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{g: W \rightarrow \mathbb{R}}$ with $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{g = (\mu_1 = \nu_1)}$ is induced, also making it a fibred product. But I am not sure if this can be done in general. My question would be if it is always possible to find $X \times_Y X \rightarrow X$ such that the symmetrical diagram holds, but I wasn't able to find much more explaining this case of a fibred product.

I think your first diagram has a typo since you wrote $p_{12}$ twice.

Your third diagram does not make sense either. Why do you write $p_1 : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$?

No, of course not, just work in $\text{Set}$ and take $Y$ to be a point.

@NaïmFavier Ah I see thanks, I fixed it.

That is still not a pullback. The composite $p^1 \circ g = (\mu_1, 0)$ is not equal to $\mu$, and similarly for $\nu$.

@NaïmFavier I see the issue, thank you again

For any morphism $f:X \to Y$, the two projection maps $X \times_{Y} X \to X$ are equal if and only if $f$ is a monomorphism (if and only if one of the projection maps is an isomorphism if and only if the diagonal map $X \to X \times_{Y} X$ is an isomorphism).

@GeoffreyTrang I think I understand, thank you. Could you check my answer to see if this is what you meant?

If the projection maps are the same, then
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X \times_Y X @>{p}>> X\\
@V{p}VV @V{\pi}VV\\
X @>{\pi}>> Y
\end{CD}
is a fibred product. Hence if $W \in \mathscr{C}$ fulfills the diagram
\begin{CD}
W @>{\mu}>> X\\
@V{\nu}VV @V{\pi}VV\\
X @>{\pi}>> Y
\end{CD}
which is equivalent to $\pi \circ \mu = \pi \circ \nu,$ then there exists a unique morphism $f: W \rightarrow X \times_Y X$ such that $\mu = p \circ f$ and $\nu = p \circ f,$ so $\mu = p \circ f = \nu.$ Thus if $\pi \circ \mu = \pi \circ \nu,$ then $\mu = \nu,$ i.e. $\pi$ is a monomorphism. So the answer to my question is that in general this doesn't hold.
